# Cannot connect to database with latest update

Tags: database, localhost

I installed the latest version of MAMP and now I can't get connected to my localhost.  It says error connecting to database... When I go to the MAMP start page it doesn't even give me the option for phpmyadmin. MAMP is open and both servers say they are connected, my folder in MAMP is pointing to the right place.  I've been working on this website for over a month now...﻿

Comment: Is the user account pointing directly to the correct database with the password, and everything?

Comment: Okay, I was finally able to connect to myPHPadmin by changing the PHP version back one version in the MAMP preferences.  But my database is GONE.  I recreated it using the exact same username and password, but one my dashboard opens it's like I'm starting from scratch. Is there any backup of it within my wordpress folders or do I have to start over?  (I do have a backup copy of my wordpress folder within my MAMP application htdocs.)

Comment: So, I've tried replacing my new db folder with my backup db folder and now it won't connect to the MySQL server again.

Comment: Now I've replaced my entire MAMP folder with my backup copy and it still won't connect to the MySQL database.  Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I am now connected to my database but when I try and log in to my site, it wants me to "install Wordpress".  When I look at my database with phpMyAdmin, I can see that all my files are there.  I definitely don't want to reinstall Wordpress, so what do I do?